# Computed property not triggered (add to Set)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, computed-properties

*Disclaimer: new to javascript*

I was just trying to trace all the current errors within a component in the following way, but I do not get what I am doing wrong. My errors set is updated each time the username changes, that said, my computed property *displayErrors* based on *errors* Set should also change:

#### Html component

```
<ol v-if="displayErrors">
  <li v-for="e in errors" v-bind:key="e">
    {{ e }}
  </li>
<ol>
```

#### Data

```
data: function () {
    return {
      username: "",
      errors: new Set(),
    }
  }
```

#### Watchers and methods

```
watch: {
    username: function (username) {
      this.checkUsernameAvailability(username)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async checkUsernameAvailability(username) {
      const errorCode = 'usernameNotAvailable'

      try {

        const response = await this.$apollo.query({ query: GET_USERS_QUERY })
        const users = response.data.users

        const usernames = users.map((user) => { return user.username })
        
        if (usernames.includes(username)) {
          this.errors.add(errorCode)
        } else {
          this.errors.delete(errorCode)
        }
        
        // trying to force the computed property
        this.$forceUpdate()

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return false
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Computed property

```
computed: {
    displayErrors: function() {
      console.log('triggered', this.errors.size)
      return this.errors.size > 0
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: new set() is not wokring with Vue. better to use Array in order to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` cannot be observed by Vue, only plain objects.

The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) for the `data` property explain this (which also applies to computed properties):

> The data object for the Vue instance. Vue will recursively convert its properties into getter/setters to make it "reactive". **The object must be plain**: native objects such as browser API objects and prototype properties are ignored. A rule of thumb is that data should just be data - it is not recommended to observe objects with their own stateful behavior.

You should use an array to store the list of errors.